# Install OpenWhisk CLI on mac

Tags: openwhisk

I am unable to install OpenWhisk command line for some reason. I download the CLI and double click to run it. I see a terminal window saying

```
[Process Complete]
```

But then it says

```
-bash: wsk: command not found
```

Comment: you can now `brew install wsk`.

Answer (score 9):

The OpenWhisk command line is not an installer but rather the binary itself. Open your **Terminal.app**, navigate to the folder you downloaded the binary to (like `cd ~/Downloads`) and use the binary from there, for example `./wsk action list`.

To be able to use the binary from everywhere, you'll have to make sure its in the `PATH`. To achieve that, either alter your `PATH` to include the folder where `wsk` is located or copy the binary to a folder already contained in your path like `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: I tried that but that still din't help. I ran the 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/SBD/Dropbox/bluemix/wsk' and then 'echo "$PATH"' It shows up there but there the same error '-bash: wsk: command not found'. I download the Mac executable and unzip n ran that too. But it didnt help

Comment: I also when into the folder and ran ./wsk it shows me the info and then still nothing "command not found". Is it possible to share a video tutorial if you know of any to install?

Comment: Where can i get the OpenWhisk command line Binary from Bluemix. I only get a wsk executable?

Comment: You should be almost there. Your PATH is slightly off, it should be: export PATH=$PATH:/Users/SBD/Dropbox/bluemix/ (drop the wsk).

Answer (score 6):

1. Download wsk cli from [here](https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net/cli/go/download/).
2. Go to downloads folder and modify permissions for `wsk` file using terminal

   `$ chmod +x ./wsk`
3. Move `wsk` to `use/local/bin` folder using terminal. This will add `wsk` to the `PATH`

   `$ sudo mv wsk /usr/local/bin`
4. Test this using following command:

   `$ wsk --help`

Answer (score 2):

Try `./wsk`,
if that works, you can update your path: `PATH = $PATH:.`  then just use the `wsk`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), I added a tap so you can easily install the `wsk` binary from a MacOS terminal: https://github.com/shaftoe/homebrew-wsk

```
brew install shaftoe/wsk/wsk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the binary from the below url and then use .wsk from the folder where you place this binary into.
https://openwhisk.ng.bluemix.net/cli/go/download/mac/