# Can we use openwhisk cli without IBM Bluemix account?

Tags: openwhisk

As we know that openwhisk is an open source project, I wanted to know if we can use it without bluemix account. I tried to install the openwhisk and the installation was successful but when I tried to install the cli it asked for the api host which they gave in example was of bluemix. So is there any other way we can get the cli or is there any other api hostname?

PS: Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to follow [this](https://thenewstack.io/hands-guide-creating-first-serverless-application-apache-openwhisk/) article.

This article also uses Vagrant as VM. 
You need to modify the permission and add wsk to path and point it to your Vagrant box.

EDIT: Follow the article or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954106) to see how to add `wsk` cli to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You may deploy openwhisk yourself (either using Vagrant, or one of the supported hosts like Ubuntu and Mac). Then your API host becomes your local installation's IP address. You will find more details on how to install openwhisk and deploy it yourself here:

- Vagrant: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/tree/master/tools/vagrant
- Ubuntu: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/tree/master/tools/ubuntu-setup
- Mac: https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/tree/master/tools/macos

Comment: I am using Vagrant and when I try to use the wsk command it says command not found. Can you please help.